# addFieldVariables not functioning with string data

Tags: plugin-sproutforms

I have the following code:

```
    {% set query = {} %}

     {% if not craft.request.getParam('q')|length %}
          {#.. key, value pairing .. #}
          {% set query = query | merge({(key):(value)}) %}
     {% else %}
          {% set query = craft.request.getParam('q') %}
     {% endif %}

     {% set queryStr = query|join(' OR ') %}

     {% do craft.sproutForms.addFieldVariables({ queryStr: queryStr }) %}   

     {{ craft.sproutForms.displayForm('requestcsv') }}
```

When I add {{queryStr}} to my hidden field in requestcsv, it doesn't populate. I can output {{queryStr}} on the page, and even so, it doesn't get passed.

Is there something I'm missing in order to be able to pass this string to a hidden field? {{queryStr}} is just a plain string.

Comment: Can you try using single brace syntax: `{queryStr}` or object syntax `{{ object.queryStr }}` as the Hidden Field value.

Comment: {queryStr} did not work, but  {{ object.queryStr }} did. I'll mark the answer if you decide to post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value you place in your Hidden Field settings gets treated as a template and whatever values you pass o the `addFieldVariables` method are treated as the object that gets parsed by that template.

Just like, when you load an Entry page in Craft, Craft provides the `entry` variable to the template, when we process the Hidden Field settings, Sprout Forms provides the `addFieldVariables` variables to that template.

While Craft knows it is giving you an Entry and names it's variable `entry`, Sprout Forms doesn't really know what you might be giving it, so it names the variable available to your settings template a generic term: `object`.

You can access these values using Object Syntax, in the same way you can using the Title Format behavior for Sections:

```
{{ object.variableName }}
```

Or in your case:

```
{{ object.queryStr }}
```

In some cases, you can also use a shorthand to output the value with a single curly brace: `{queryStr}`.